# Cannot get properties of an object after using filter()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to use filter() to isolate an object from an array of objects, and then present that object's title in React.

The oneliner looks like this:

```
 {Object.values(articles).filter(e => e.id==36)[0].title}
```

Now after filtering, i get an array of size 1, with the object i want:

```
{Object.values(articles).filter(e => e.id==36).map(e =>
 console.log(e))}
```

Outputs:

```
> Object { id: 36, title: "Fine landskap i ny dokumentar", img:
> "/images/landscape2.jpg", date: "2019-10-31 11:49", author: "The
> Onion", ingress: "Heyo", content: "Helt fantastisk", category:
> "Kultur", rating: 2 }
```

My problem is, when i try to add a [0].title after the filter function, i get a TypeError saying:

> TypeError: Object.values(...).filter(...)[0] is undefined

Which doesn't make sense either, because:

```
{Object.values(articles).filter(e => e.id==36).length}
```

Outputs 1.

When i call it with just the [0] though, i get a reasonable error.

```
{Object.values(articles).filter(e => e.id==36)[0]}
```

Outputs:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {id, title, img, date, author, ingress, content, category, rating}).
>   If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

The filter function has obviously given me an array with the object i want, but i cannot access any of the object's properties.

Comment: Can you try the following: `(Object.values(articles).find(e => e.id==36)||{title:'not found'}).title`. I suspect it renders multiple times and maybe the first time articles is an empty array.

Comment: Is your component rendering once before your data has fetched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's strange this doesn't work...

You can try `find`. It will return the object you looking for:

```
{Object.values(articles).find(a => a.id==36).title || 'fallback if article is not found'}
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s because when you call with the first index [0] you access to the first object present in your array an try to render it. But you can’t render an object directly in React.

So I imagine you’re inside the render method of your component.

```
render () { 
  const filteredObjects = Object.values(articles).filter( article => article.id === 36)

  return filteredObjects.map( article => {
    <div>
      <h1> {article.title} </h1>
    </div>
  })
}
```

But as I understand you want to get only one object the one which has **id** value of 36. So maybe you can consider to use `.find()` method instead.

```
const findObjectId = Object.values(articles).find( article => article.id === 36)
```

Of course you can one line this :

```
{ Object.values(articles).find( article => article.id === 36).title || ‘ No object found with this id ‘ }
```

Using find() will not return an array but the first object corresponding to the predicate.

I imagine your input is an object of objects but if I’m wrong feel free to give me your input  structure so I can adapt my answer to your needs.